# Can we able to print the object along with the xpath in Page object model

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I am using POM using testng+java+maven.Can we able to print By objectname in the logs/extendreport for the reporting purpose?
I am using Log4j and extentreports.

Example : My **commonfunction** class contains all the actions perform for the testcases:

```
public void click(By element) {
        WebElement webElement = getElement(element);
        try {

            Log.info("Clicking on the webelement " + element);
            webElement.click();
            ExtentTestManager.getTest().info("clicking on the webelement - " + element);
        }

        catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            Log.error(e.getMessage());
            ExtentTestManager.getTest().fail(e);
            throw new TestException(String.format("The following element is not clickable: [%s]", element));
        }
    }
```

and in my **pageobject** class im declaring xpath as:

```
By clearFormButton = By.xpath("//*[@id='createPopulation:j_idt198']");

and in my test step:
commonfunction.click(clearFormButton);

Actual output : Clicking on the webelement By.xpath: 
//*[@id='createPopulation:j_idt198']

Expected output : Clicking on the webelement clearFormButton - By.xpath: 
//*[@id='createPopulation:j_idt198']
```

Comment: Please, please, please don't use XPath when you are just locating an element by ID. Use `By.id()` instead.

Comment: Do you really want to look through a sea of successful clicks to find the one that doesn't work? Don't log clicks, instead learn how to read the stack trace when it fails and throws an error. That stack trace will tell you EXACTLY which line the script failed on along with locator information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Reflection mechanism](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javareflection-1536171.html) to get the value of [foundBy](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/selenium-3.141.59/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebElement.java#L58) field of the [RemoteWebElement](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebElement.html) class instance like:

```
java.lang.reflect.Field field = element.getClass().getDeclaredField("foundBy");
field.setAccessible(true);
String foundBy = field.get(element).toString();
```

[image]

Your implementation of the [Page Object Model design pattern](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Design+Patterns+-+Page+Object+Model) is a little bit weird, by the way, my vision is that your test should not have any Selenium internals, so instead of having `commonfunction.click(clearFormButton);` in the test step you should be having something like `CreatePopulationPage page = myCurrentPage.clickCreatePopulationButton();`

Answer (score 0):

The `e.extraInfo.get("*** Element info")` will give you locator and it's value.

log.debug(e.extraInfo.get("*** Element info"))

```
public void click(By element) {
        WebElement webElement = getElement(element);
        try {

            Log.info("Clicking on the webelement " + element);
            webElement.click();
            ExtentTestManager.getTest().info("clicking on the webelement - " + element);
        }

        catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            log.debug(e.extraInfo.get("*** Element info"))
            Log.error(e.getMessage());
            ExtentTestManager.getTest().fail(e);
            throw new TestException(String.format("The following element is not clickable: [%s]", e.extraInfo.get("*** Element info"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: where By type variable name "element " will be printed in the code ?

Comment: Question asks for printing By variable name in log.info or in extent report log for information, but here answer only caters something when exception occurs ??